# Calculate EBBI from Landsat 8 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, formula

I am trying to calculate EBBI from Landsat 8 in Google Earth Engine (GEE) but I am getting this error: `Error: Image.parseExpression: Expression parse error at character 30: '(SWIR - NIR)/ (10 * Image.sqrt(SWIR + TIRS))' ^. (Error code: 3)`. The channels for this index are the SWIR, NIR and Thermal, 30m resolution for the two and 100m for the last channel. This might cause the issue but when I calculate the index in a GIS software I have no problem. Can you please help? The image shows how to calculate the index (for Landsat 7) and here is the [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0bb5d606b5a322bddaa9bd29324dd81e) I used:

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
//Create mask function
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 2, 3 and 5 are water, cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var waterBitMask = (1 << 2);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0))
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(waterBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
//Create Image Collection for Landsat 8 BOA, filtering data from April 2013 to December 2013
//filtering the tiles which intersect India, selecting the predefined bands (VIS, NIR and SWIR)
//Display results
var landsat = landsat.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(4,4,'month'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2013,2013,'year'))
                      .filterBounds(table)
.map(maskL8sr);
var landsat = landsat.select('B5','B6','B10')
print (landsat)

//Calculate the median for each band (B2 to B7), multiply by scale factor
//(0.0001), and clip to country polygon
var median1 = landsat.select('B5','B6').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).multiply(0.0001).clip(table);

//Calculate the median for B10, multiply by scale factor
//(0.1), and clip to country polygon
var median2 = landsat.select('B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).multiply(0.1).clip(table);
Map.addLayer(median1)
Map.addLayer(median2)

//Create variable for each band
var B5 = median1.select('B5_median')
var B6 = median1.select('B6_median')
var B10 = median2.select('B10_median')

// calculate EBBI
var ebbi = median1.expression('(SWIR - NIR)/ 10 * Image.sqrt(SWIR + TIRS)',
{
'NIR':median1.select('B5_median'),
'SWIR':median1.select('B6_median'),
'TIRS' : median2.select('B10_median')
});
```

[image: ebbi formula]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your asset 'users/nikostziokas/delhi' is not accessible for me, I assumed an arbitrary geometry in USA for adequately running your script. I put a print instruction for ebbi image for watching produced error with correct expression for this variable; as it can be observed as follows.

```
// calculate EBBI
var ebbi = median1.expression('(SWIR - NIR)/ 10 * sqrt(SWIR + TIRS)',
{
'NIR':median1.select('B5_median'),
'RED':median1.select('B4_median'),
'BLUE':median1.select('B2_median'),
'TIRS' : median1.select('B10_median')
});
```

Obtained error was:

> Image (Error) Image.parseExpression: Expression contains undeclared
> variables: [SWIR]

So, compared to your image formula:

[image: ebbi formula]

following code snippet fixes all issues detected.

```
var landsat = landsat.select('B4','B5','B6','B10');
print (landsat);

//Calculate the median for each band (B2 to B7), multiply by scale factor
//(0.0001), and clip to country polygon
var median1 = landsat.select('B4', 'B5','B6').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).multiply(0.0001).clip(table);

//Calculate the median for B10, multiply by scale factor
//(0.1), and clip to country polygon
var median2 = landsat.select('B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).multiply(0.1).clip(table);
Map.addLayer(median1);
Map.addLayer(median2);

//Create variable for each band
var B4 = median1.select('B4_median');
var B5 = median1.select('B5_median');
var B6 = median1.select('B6_median');
var B10 = median2.select('B10_median');

// calculate EBBI
var ebbi = median1.expression('(SWIR - NIR)/ 10 * sqrt(SWIR + TIRS)',
{
'SWIR':median1.select('B5_median'),
'NIR':median1.select('B4_median'),
'TIRS' : median1.select('B6_median')
}).rename('EBBI');

print(ebbi);
```

After running complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f965d3b071985332f233a15026a3f312) in GEE, I got following result:

[image]

Now, ebbi image is printed without any error.

Comment: Thank you @xunilk, it works perfectly. Also, I saw I posted a wrong code so I edited the data for the EBBI calculation.